# MS-SQL bulk-import from csv using bcp with format file

Tags: sql-server, xml, csv, format, bcp

I have trouble getting bcp to import my data from a csv file. I have narrowed down the problem to have something to do with the format file. I suspect it may be a misconfiguration, but I can't figure out where exactly I'm wrong.

My table is XXX.dbo.test, with a single VARCHAR(50) column named 'banana'.

My data.csv file contains four rows:

```
aaaaaaaaaaaaa
bbbbbbbbbbbbb
ccccccccccccc
ddddddddddddd
```

where the linebreak is CR-LF.

My format file is in xml format, named format.xml and contains:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<BCPFORMAT xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/bulkload/format" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
 <RECORD>
  <FIELD ID="1" xsi:type="CharPrefix" PREFIX_LENGTH="2" MAX_LENGTH="50" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
 </RECORD>
 <ROW>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="1" NAME="banana" xsi:type="SQLVARYCHAR"/>
 </ROW>
</BCPFORMAT>
```

When I run

```
bcp XXX.dbo.test in data.csv -c -T -S myserver,port
```

result is

```
Starting copy...

4 rows copied.
Network packet size (bytes): 4096
Clock Time (ms.) Total     : 109    Average : (36.70 rows per sec.)
```

So that is good.

If instead I run

```
bcp XXX.dbo.test in data.csv -f format.xml -T -S myserver,port
```

the result is

```
Starting copy...

0 rows copied.
Network packet size (bytes): 4096
Clock Time (ms.) Total     : 16
```

What is wrong with my format.xml?

Thank you.

Comment: On the very first glimps there is a typo: `xsi:type="SQLVARYCHAR"`. I do not know a data type VAR**Y**CHAR ...

Comment: Thanks for the comment (and the edit!). I've generated the xml file using bcp's format option, so it should be correct. More Info (scroll ~75%) down): https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189327%28v=sql.105%29.aspx . I've verified by changing SQLVARYCHAR to XXX, which gives me an error:
SQLState = HY000, NativeError = 0
Error = [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0][SQL Server]The value of attribute xsi:type is incorrect in xml format file for the field at line 7 column 62.
Using the other CHAR-Types, bcp will still only tell me that 0 rows have been imported.